# Data binding in nested component with Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ui-router, angular-components

In my Angular project I have some components which loads in parent component and Angular UI Router state. I send the "fields' variable in Page Component.

index.js

```
...
angular.
module('generalApp').
config(['$stateProvider',
    function config($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('settings', {
                url: '/settings',
                component: 'page',
                resolve: {
                    type: function() {
                        return "form";
                    },
                    fields: function() {
                        return require("./data/settingsFields.json");
                    }
                }
            })
    }
]);
...
```

page.component.js

```
...
angular.
module('page').
component('page', {
    bindings: {
        type: '@',
        fields: '<'
    },
    template: '...<form-page ng-if="$ctrl.type"></form-page>...',
    controller: [function PageController() {
        ...
        }
    ]
});
...
```

and formPage.component.js

```
...
angular.
module('formPage').
component('formPage', {
    bindings: {
        fields: '<'
    },
    template: require('./formPage.template.html'),
    controller: [function formPageController() {
    ...
    }]
});
...
```

I can to get "fields" variable in Page Component and I want to get it in nested FormPage Component. What I should do for this?